# PHP - multi-thread jobs working with Google Cloud API

Tags: php, multithreading, laravel, gearman, microprocessors

I created a Saas that collect orders from different websites for companies,
the websites are kind of "publishers" that provide the company orders every day.

I don't have an API so I'm scraping HTML from those websites by using the username and password that the company provides me.

After importing and saving the orders in my database, I'm sending them to the company's printer using Google cloud print API and the company working on the order in real-time.

After the order has been sent to print, I'm sending a post request to the website that basically clicking on a button that says "I got the order and I'm working on it", kind of accepting/approving the order.

the company has a UI that shows them a table of today's orders, for each order, they can see that the order has been approved and sent to the printer by google cloud print and they assume that the order was really printed.

So far, so good, but I have a big issue.

sometimes google cloud print doesn't recognize the printer and the company has to restart the computer that is connected to the printer, the issue is that my UI shows the user that the order has already been printed and also approving the order on the original website so the clients got an approvment that the company is working on the order right now.

google cloud print API provides me the option to check the status of the print but it takes about 6 seconds and maybe the status is "in progress" so it will take me more than 6 seconds for 1 order to get the status I wish for - "done".

right now I have a 2 cron jobs that run every minute,
the first is importing new orders and second sending new orders to print.
when I send an order to print it takes about 4 seconds, so i can send only up to 15 orders per minute, as I said the companies are working in real-time so I cant have any delay from the moment that the order appears in one of the websites to the moment it comes out the printer

I wish that i worked like that:

step 1:
import the order

step 2:
send it to the printer

step 3: 
check the status

step 4:
approve the order on the website after I got a "done" status.

I think that my biggest issue is that it's not working with multi-threads

I'm looking for the best way to manage and work with multi-thread jobs in PHP.

Comment: For step 2. Is sending to a printer really necessary?  Generating a PDF and emailing it might be more efficient and puts printing in control of the user.

Comment: the company has to receive the order directly to the printer